# I have a technical interview for a spatial data analyst position - what should I expect?

Tags: interviewing

The job is handling spatial data for a public health research study. I don't have any specifics about the interview other than the interviewer, who is the lead GIS analyst for this organization. I assume there will be questions about projects I've done and maybe a live exercise. Is there somewhere I can find data-related practice exercises that would be helpful? Is there anything I'm missing or should prepare for?

Comment: To be asked about analysing spatial data?

Comment: I work in a similar role. Expect to be asked about your experience in GIS (ESRI, QGIS etc), obtaining data from various data sources, Python scripting, various spatial operations (intersecting, voronoi polygons, heatmaps), ETL (eg using SSIS) and probably database maintenance (or geodatabase if they're an ESRI shop) - maybe some postgres or spatial SQL.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there somewhere I can find data-related practice exercises that would be helpful? Is there anything I'm missing or should prepare for?

If you are applying to such position one would assume or expected that you actually know about spatial data analysis, so it puzzles me a bit that you are asking such question.

If you know about such topics then I suggest you **rehearse or go over the things you know, the tools you know how to use, past projects you could mention**, etc.. We can't guess what they are going to ask you in the interview, so be prepared to showcase all your knowledge on the matter.

Now, if you don't know about spatial data analysis then it is very unlikely that you will learn what's needed by doing some practice exercises on the topic, and even if you somehow managed to get hired this could turn into an ordeal later on (and will eventually be obvious that you are not fit for the role).